# Icons Won't Show Up Correctly Flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

More often than not, the icons I select to display will not show up (or will show up incorrectly) throughout my entire application. I'm not importing any new icons, all of the ones I use are selected from Flutter's default library.

On Android devices it is pretty much hit-or-miss; either all of the icons show up correctly, or they all give the same error placeholder. Like I said its much more often that they do not show.

[image: Android AppBar Icon Working]

[image: Android AppBar Icon Not Working]

[image: Android Drawer Working]

[image: Android Drawer Not Working]

iOS is a different story, while they still usually don't work correctly, it sometimes gives random emojis instead of the correct icon or error boxes. As you can see in the second picture, it placed a forward arrow emoji in place of what should have been the list-like icon to open the Drawer. Previously, the Close icon inside the Drawer was displaying as the strong arm emoji.

[image: iOS Error Boxes]

[image: iOS Random Emoji]

```
return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.format_align_center),
      onPressed: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
    ),
    title: Text(
      "INFORMATION",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Titillium SemiBold',
        fontSize: 37.0,
      ),
    ),
    centerTitle: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0.5,
  ),
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              height: 150.0,
              color: Colors.white.withRed(191).withGreen(194).withBlue(200),
              child: FittedBox(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "VITALITY PRO",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
              )
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              "TERMS & CONDITIONS",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/terms'),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              "PRIVACY POLICY",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/privacy'),
          ),
          Divider(),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              "CLOSE",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0
              ),
            ),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          Divider(),
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.loose,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "LOGOUT",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black38,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/origin'),
                  ),
                  Text("@Copyright 2018, ISPA Technology, LLC"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

[image: Flutter Doctor]

[image: Flutter Version]

Comment: What Flutter version are you using? Is this a real device or the emulator?

Comment: Flutter version: 25.0.1, and its a virtual device. the working on is a Nexus S, the one not working is a Pixel 2. But different ones work at different times.

Comment: There is no Flutter version 25.0.1. Can you please add the output of `flutter doctor` to your question?

Comment: sure, here you go

Comment: I see. That's the IDE Flutter plugin version. The Flutter version is 0.4.4. There is 5.1.0 from the `beta` channel already.

Answer (score 0):

That's a known issue that was fixed since.

Run

```
flutter upgrade
```

to get a newer Flutter version where this fix is included.

Comment: I ran and updated both Studio and my plugins, but my icons are performing the same.

New flutter doctor msg:

`C:\Users\Maria\Downloads\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: Seems I'm mistaken. The issue doesn't seem to be fixed https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17485